# use r base function to find the relatively min value of each row in matrix but each min value at different column

Tags: r

I have a matrix like this

```
d <- matrix(c(10, -20, -30, 20, 30,
              10, -15, -30, 20, 30,
              10, 40, -30, 20, 30,
              10, -20, -30, 20, 40), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)

# > d
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   10  -20  -30   20   30
# [2,]   10  -15  -30   20   30
# [3,]   10   40  -30   20   30
# [4,]   10  -20  -30   20   40
```

I want to find the index of each row min value whose abs value is less equal 25,
but each row min value should at different column.
I use for loop to do it like this, which is not good enough.

```
rng <- 25
ok <- abs(d) < rng
res <- rep(NA, 4)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(d))) {
    if (any(ok[i, ])) {
        dd <- d[i, ]
        idx <- which(ok[i, ])
        idx.min <- idx[which.min(dd[idx])]
        res[i] <- idx.min
        ok[, idx.min] <- FALSE
    }
}
res
```

the result is this

```
# > res
# [1]  2  1  4 NA
```

which means that the index of the first row is 2, whose value is -20.
and since the second column is used,
although the min value of the second row is still in the second column,
it should be the first column value 10, and the index is 1.
If it can not find the min value, the index is NA.

Is there vectorizing function that can do this?
thanks guys. If there is any English expression problem, please also tell me.

Comment: `each row min value should at different column` what does that mean? How do you determine which column should be used for which row? Is this an optimization problem? Or is this done sequentially, i.e. sequentially removing the columns which were max at the previous rows?

Comment: this is done sequentially

Comment: I prefer to use base function to do it

Comment: With the posted data the posted result is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: sorry, where is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the column index with the minimal *absolute* value for each row, you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- matrix(c(
  10, -20, -30, 20, 30,
  10, -15, -30, 20, 30,
  10, 40, -30, 20, 30,
  10, -20, -30, 20, 40
), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)

d %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "row") %>%
  pivot_longer(-row, names_to = "col") %>%
  mutate(col = col %>% str_extract("[0-9]+") %>% as.numeric()) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  # only consider values with small abs volaue
  filter(abs(value) < 25) %>%
  # get the smallest value
  arrange(abs(value)) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  # get column indicies
  pull(col)
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> Using compatibility `.name_repair`.
#> [1] 1 1 1 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Is this your expected result?

Comment: thanks for you answer. I prefer use base function to do it.lol

Comment: Base R requirement was not mentioned in your question.

Comment: so sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R way. It sets each value in the columns already in `ok` and each value not less than `rng` to `Inf`. And uses `which.min` to find the minima per row.

```
rng <- 25
ok <- rep(NA_integer_, nrow(d))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(d))) {
  x <- abs(d[i,])
  x[ok] <- Inf
  x[x >= rng] <- Inf
  if(any(is.finite(x))) ok[i] <- which.min(x)
}

ok
#[1]  1  2  4 NA
```

Comment: thanks for your hint. And I learn a new constant NA_integer_. It seems like your answer is different from me.

Comment: @Paul Yes, mine is different. The 1st minimum is in column 1, not 2. Your result in the question has the first 2 values swapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `for` loop like below

```
res <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  v <- d[i, ]
  idx <- abs(v) <= 25 & !(1:ncol(d) %in% res)
  if (all(!idx)) {
    res <- c(res, NA)
  } else {
    res <- c(res, which(v == min(v[idx])))
  }
}
```

and you will see

```
> res
[1]  2  1  4 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that removes the chosen column at each iteration.

```
d <- matrix(c(10, -20, -30, 20, 30,
              10, -15, -30, 20, 30,
              10, 40, -30, 20, 30,
              10, -20, -30, 20, 40), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)

d[abs(d) > 25] <- NA
res <- integer(nrow(d))
# rbind the column index
d <- rbind(1:ncol(d), d)

for (i in 2:nrow(d)) {
  idx <- which.min(d[i,])
  
  if (length(idx)) {
    res[i - 1L] <- d[1, idx]
    d <- d[, -idx]
  } else {
    res[i - 1L] <- NA
  }
}

res
#> [1]  2  1  4 NA
```